# I need to merge elements of sublist in python

Tags: python, list, sublist

i have following data lists

```
data1 = [[4,5,9],[4,7,2],[11,13,15]]
data2 = [[1,2,3,7],[3,6,8,5],[12,10,15,17]]
```

i want the merging of list to be done as follows.

```
data = [[4,5,9,1,2,3,7], [4,7,2,3,6,8,5], [11,13,15,12,10,15,17]]
```

i.e. merging the elements at index 0 in data1 and data2 and merging the elements at index 1 in data1 and data 2 and so on..

```
data1 = [[4,5,9],[4,7,2],[11,13,15]]
data2 = [[1,2,3,7],[3,6,8,5],[12,10,15,17]]
for i in range (0,2):
    for j in range(0,3):
        data1[i].extend(data2[j])
print(data1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure `data1` and `data2` always have same number of elements (sublists) you could use `map` following way:

```
data1 = [[4,5,9],[4,7,2],[11,13,15]]
data2 = [[1,2,3,7],[3,6,8,5],[12,10,15,17]]
data = list(map(lambda x,y:x+y,data1,data2))
print(data)
```

output:

```
[[4, 5, 9, 1, 2, 3, 7], [4, 7, 2, 3, 6, 8, 5], [11, 13, 15, 12, 10, 15, 17]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `zip()` with list-comprehension:

```
data1 = [[4,5,9],[4,7,2],[11,13,15]] 
data2 = [[1,2,3,7],[3,6,8,5],[12,10,15,17]]

data = [x+y for x, y in zip(data1, data2)]
# [[4, 5, 9, 1, 2, 3, 7], [4, 7, 2, 3, 6, 8, 5], [11, 13, 15, 12, 10, 15, 17]]
```

---

If you need it in normal loops way, you can get rid of one loop in your code (assuming both lists are of equal length):

```
data1 = [[4,5,9],[4,7,2],[11,13,15]]
data2 = [[1,2,3,7],[3,6,8,5],[12,10,15,17]]

for i in range(len(data1)):
    data1[i].extend(data2[i])

print(data1)
# [[4, 5, 9, 1, 2, 3, 7], [4, 7, 2, 3, 6, 8, 5], [11, 13, 15, 12, 10, 15, 17]]
```

Comment: both options seem to be working fine, and are fast. See my answer with timing comparissons.

Comment: @Ralf, great. Thanks for coming up with timing comparisons.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
data_to_merge = [data1,data2]
merged = [sum(ds,[]) for ds in zip(*data_to_merge)]
```

You could also use numpy's `hstack`, which I find a bit more intuitive

```
merged = np.hstack(data_to_merge)
```

Comment: using `sum` to sum 2 lists looks really bloated.

Comment: Using `sum` is better than adding if the OP has more than two `data1`,`data2` etc variables.

Comment: no because performance suffers. sum has a quadratic complexity on lists.

Comment: Use numpy's `hstack` then.

Comment: The [documentation on sum](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sum) recommends using `itertools.chain` to concatenate iterables. eg. `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*data_to_merge)))`

Comment: @Rob both of your solutions work with multiple lists, but are considerably slower as the options in the other answer (not to discredit them, just that you all are aware of the difference). See my answer with timing comparisson.

Answer (score 2):

I compared the solutions given in other answers:

```
def f1(original_data):
    return [
        x+y
        for x, y in zip(*original_data)]

def f2(original_data):
    return [
        sum(x, [])
        for x in zip(*original_data)]

def f3(original_data):
    data_1 = original_data[0]
    data_2 = original_data[1]

    for i in range(len(data_1)):
        data_1[i].extend(data_2[i])

    return data_1

def f4(original_data):
    return np.hstack(original_data).tolist()
```

And the timings are:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('f(data)', 'from __main__ import data,  f1 as f')
0.6496335420088144
>>> timeit.timeit('f(data)', 'from __main__ import data,  f2 as f')
1.1647848110005725
>>> timeit.timeit('f(data)', 'from __main__ import data,  f3 as f')
0.6762638779910048
>>> timeit.timeit('f(data)', 'from __main__ import data,  f4 as f')
8.561359490995528
```

The version in my `f1()` seems to be the fastest for these short lists.

Note: be careful with the code in `f3()`, because it modifies the original data, so you have to run it as the last one; the other functions return a new copy and don't touch the original.

One difference is, that the version in `f2()` works for multiple lists, not just 2; but it is slower. `f4()` (using `numpy`) works for multiple lists as well, but it is a LOT slower.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator `concat()` and the function `starmap()`;:

```
from operator import concat
from itertools import starmap

list(starmap(concat, zip(data1, data2)))
# [[4, 5, 9, 1, 2, 3, 7], [4, 7, 2, 3, 6, 8, 5], [11, 13, 15, 12, 10, 15, 17]]
```